# Regex to allow only numbers between 100 and 999999

Tags: c#, regex, compact-framework

Can anyone help with C# code using regular expressions to validate a textbox which accepts only numbers between 100 and 999999

Thanks,
Lui.

Comment: Would a number beginning with one or more zeroes (e.g. 00222) be valid input or not?

Comment: Which UI technology are you using? Some of them allow for Range attributes on their model and validate automatically.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need a regex for this.

```
int n;
if (!int.TryParse(textBox.Text.Trim(), out n) || n<100 || n>999999)
{
  // Display error message: Out of range or not a number
}
```

EDIT: If the CF is targetted, then you can't use `int.TryParse()`. Fallback on `int.Parse()` instead and type a little more error-catching code:

```
int n;
try
{
  int n = int.Parse(textBox.Text.Trim());
  if (n<100 || n>999999)
  {
    // Display error message: Out of range
  }
  else
  {
    // OK
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // Display error message: Not a number. 
   //   You may want to catch the individual exception types 
   //   for more info about the error
}
```

Comment: Are leading zeros allowed? If not, this solution is incomplete.

Comment: @mob: I'm user-minded. When I'm asked to validate user input, I'm not going to refuse 0100. User would reply _Stupid @#$ computer_. And she'd be right!

Comment: @serge I can't use int.TryParse() as i'm using this in a  windows mobile CF application.

Comment: use int.Parse() instead. But catch exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirement translates to three to six digits, first not zero. I can't remember whether C# anchors REs by default, so I've put them in too.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{2,5}$
```

Comment: And it's far better to express this using something other than REs.

Comment: I know this doesn't handle leading zeroes. For user input where those users aren't programmers, disallowing leading zeroes is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: Why do you think disallowing leading zeroes is "the right thing"?

Comment: @Dour: Because users — _ordinary_ users — simply _don't_ type that in real life. If there's a leading zero, it's likely because they made a mistake in typing. I've watched them, that's how they work and how they think.

Answer (score 3):

A straightforward approach would be to use the regex

```
^[1-9][0-9]{2,5}$
```

If you want to allow leading zeroes (but still keep the 6-digit limit) the regex would be

```
^(?=[0-9]{3,6}$)0*[1-9][0-9]{2,5}
```

This last one probably merits some explanation: it first uses positive lookahead [`(?=)`] to make sure that the whole input is 3 to 6 digits, and then it makes sure that it's made up of any number of leading zeroes followed by a number in the range 100-999999.

**However**, it's possibly a good idea to use something more suited to the task (maybe a numeric comparison?).

Comment: @soniiic: Sorry, can you explain that a bit?

Comment: @Jon, your second expression is not valid. You want something more like `^0*[1-9]\d{2,5}\z`

Comment: @CanSpice How is it that 100 wouldn't be accepted by `^[0-9]{3,6}$` ?

Comment: @Qtax: That was totally sloppy of me, sorry. The current answer is pretty much on target though.

Comment: @CanSpice, my regex would not do any of the things you state, and it works just fine. Seems like you missed or don't know the meaning of `\d`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick:

```
^[1-9]\d{2,5}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use regex? How about

```
int result;
if(Int.TryParse(string, out result) && result > 100 && result < 999999) {
    //do whatever with result
}
else
{
    //invalid input
}
```

Comment: Brian, I can't use int.TryParse() as i'm using this in a windows mobile CF application.

Answer (score 0):

another approach you could consider

`[1-9]\d{2,5}`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx) control instead which lets you specifiy a Minimum and Maximum value? 
And it will only allow numbers too, saving you additional validation to ensure anything non-numeric can be entered

From the example:

```
public void InstantiateMyNumericUpDown()
{
   // Create and initialize a NumericUpDown control.
   numericUpDown1 = new NumericUpDown();

   // Dock the control to the top of the form.
   numericUpDown1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;

   // Set the Minimum, Maximum, and initial Value.
   numericUpDown1.Value = 100;
   numericUpDown1.Maximum = 999999;
   numericUpDown1.Minimum = 100;

   // Add the NumericUpDown to the Form.
   Controls.Add(numericUpDown1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And maybe accepting leading zeros:

```
^0*[1-9]\d{2,5}$
```